# Oracle's Pro*C accessing from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, oracle

I am working on a C++ server that uses Oracle as a backend via Pro*C.

Right now we have a significant problem running queries on unrelated tables from multiple threads.  The documentation I could find talks about using mutexes and such for synchronization.

My experience with other databases like MySQL on Linux the issue came if you are using a single connection via multiple threads.  The problem was solved by me creating a connection handle per thread.

Is there a trick like this that will let us use Oracle Pro*C in a similar fashion?  Seems that an enterprise class DB that doesn't support functionality of this sort at version 10+ is somewhat unlikely.

Comment: Do you know about the pro*c precompiler option [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/a97269/pc_11thr.htm#i997959) and the [multithreaded programming considerations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/a97269/pc_11thr.htm#i999517)? Might be this helps... Switching to `OCCI` would make your live easier as well.

Comment: @nabulke That might work.  Put it in the answer I will accept it.  OCCI unfortunately at this stage is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know about the pro*c precompiler option [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/a97269/pc_11thr.htm#i997959) and the [multithreaded programming considerations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/a97269/pc_11thr.htm#i999517)?

> With **THREADS=YES** specified on the command line, the Pro*C/C++ Precompiler ensures that the generated code is thread-safe, given that you follow the guidelines.